# Remove keyboard toolbar in react native

Tags: react-native, input, textinput

I want to remove keyboard toolbar. You can see [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn16o.png). please tell me how can i remove keyboard toolbar.

here is my code:

```
<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={styles.messagesContainer}>
        <FlatList
          inverted={true}
          data={messages}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            const newDate = new Date(item.createdAt)
            return (
              <View style={item.user._id === 1 ? styles.messageTextContainer2 : styles.messageTextContainer}>
                <Text style={item.user._id === 1 ? styles.messageText2 : styles.messageText}>{item.text}</Text>
                <Text style={item.user._id === 1 ? styles.timeText2 : styles.timeText}>{newDate.toLocaleTimeString()}</Text>
              </View>
            )
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={setText}
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Type a message..."
          value={text}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sendContainer}>
          <Text onPress={() => onSend()} style={styles.sendText}>Send</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
```

Comment: Are you using any libraries for this(the input field), its doesn't seem to be how text inputs normally behave.

if you are struggling to find a solution, there is a package i've used in the past for this scenario that works quite well https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-accessory